# How to get rows where count() is null?

Tags: mysql, join

This is my SQL request :

```
SELECT COUNT( b0_.id ) AS sclr0, d1_.codeLieu AS codeLieu1, d1_.nomLieu AS nomLieu2,   
      d1_.lngLieu AS lngLieu3, d1_.latLieu AS latLieu4, 
      m2_.libelleMention AS libelleMention5, t3_.libelleType AS libelleType6
FROM Bac b0_
INNER JOIN Bachelier b4_ ON b0_.bachelier_cne = b4_.cne
INNER JOIN EtablissementBac e5_ ON b0_.etabBac_id = e5_.codeLieu
INNER JOIN Delegation d1_ ON e5_.delegation_id = d1_.codeLieu
INNER JOIN MentionBac m2_ ON b0_.mentionBac_id = m2_.codeMention
INNER JOIN TypeBac t3_ ON b0_.typeBac_id = t3_.codeType
WHERE m2_.codeMention IN ('TB',  'B')
AND t3_.codeType IN ('114',  '129')
GROUP BY d1_.codeLieu, m2_.codeMention, m2_.libelleMention, 
         t3_.codeType, t3_.libelleType, t3_.abbrType
ORDER BY d1_.codeLieu ASC , b0_.mentionBac_id ASC , b0_.typeBac_id ASC
```

And this is the result (it's a screenshot):

http://nsa33.casimages.com/img/2013/05/10//130510034126658849.png

The thing is I get all the rows with the equivalent number (sclr0), but I also need rows with null values. The needed rows are defined by the columns libelleMention5, libelleType6. In other words, I want for each codeLieu1, all the possible combinations of libelleMention5 and libelleType6, and the equivalent number in the column sclr0 (which should be 0 if the cell is NULL).

How can I do that ?

**EDIT**

This is the new screenshot : http://nsa34.casimages.com/img/2013/05/11//130511101655302101.png

Comment: If you want the other question you have posted 4 hours ago, to be closed, please flag it so moderators can close it (or migrate it here): [MySQL : INNER JOIN & COUNT : I need to get results that are NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478367/mysql-inner-join-count-i-need-to-get-results-that-are-null) The SE network suggests questions to be asked in 1 site only, not cross-posted.

Comment: Alright. I did.

Comment: Can you add the relationships between the tables or the `CREATE TABLE` statements?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL : INNER JOIN & COUNT : I need to get results that are NULL](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41928/mysql-inner-join-count-i-need-to-get-results-that-are-null)

Comment: I don't have the `CREATE TABLE` statements.. The relationships between tables are the ones as above in the `INNER JOIN` clauses.. I just want to know how to do it.. You can explain to me using an example of yours.. but with three or four tables (an analogy) =)

Comment: Anyone can help please ? I'm stuck on this

Comment: Are you sure you need the `b4` table? What happens if you remove it?

Comment: Yes, I need the e5 table, but the b4, not really. I removed the b4, nothing changed in the result. We can consider it as useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, without any detailed info about the tables' relationships (1-1, 1-to-many, many-to-many) and the primary keys, it's not easy to deal with this. But lets try.

The `FROM` clause has a 6-table join:

```
FROM 
  Bac              b0_  INNER JOIN 
  Bachelier        b4_   ON b0_.bachelier_cne = b4_.cne INNER JOIN 
  EtablissementBac e5_   ON b0_.etabBac_id = e5_.codeLieu INNER JOIN 
  Delegation       d1_   ON e5_.delegation_id = d1_.codeLieu INNER JOIN 
  MentionBac       m2_   ON b0_.mentionBac_id = m2_.codeMention INNER JOIN 
  TypeBac          t3_   ON b0_.typeBac_id = t3_.codeType
```

Since 2 tables (`m2_` and `t3_`) are involved in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE m2_.codeMention IN ('TB',  'B')
  AND t3_.codeType IN ('114',  '129')
```

and one more (`d1_`) in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
GROUP BY 
  d1_.codeLieu, 
  m2_.codeMention, m2_.libelleMention, 
  t3_.codeType, t3_.libelleType, t3_.abbrType
```

we'll assume that these 3 should be join with proper `INNER` joins.

And since you are counting on `b0_`, this will probably have to be `"LEFT"` joined. That leaves with some choices about the other two tables (`b4_` and `e5_`). So, lets rewrite the `FROM` part. First the 3 (sure `JOIN`) tables, then the ambiguous 2 and lastly the sure (`LEFT JOIN`) `b0_`:

```
FROM 
  TypeBac          t3_  INNER JOIN 
  MentionBac       m2_  INNER JOIN 
  Delegation       d1_  INNER JOIN 

  EtablissementBac e5_   ON e5_.delegation_id = d1_.codeLieu INNER JOIN 
  Bachelier        b4_  
                        LEFT JOIN
  Bac              b0_   ON b0_.bachelier_cne = b4_.cne 
                        AND b0_.etabBac_id = e5_.codeLieu 
                        AND b0_.typeBac_id = t3_.codeType
                        AND b0_.mentionBac_id = m2_.codeMention
```

Well, that doesn't look correct. Because (except for the `d1` - `e5` join), we don't have a way to join the other 4 tables. All 4 are to be joined with the `b4` which has to be last (as we want to `LEFT JOIN` it.) This observation leaves with one choice:

```
FROM 
  TypeBac          t3_  CROSS JOIN 
  MentionBac       m2_  CROSS JOIN 
  Delegation       d1_  INNER JOIN 

  EtablissementBac e5_   ON e5_.delegation_id = d1_.codeLieu 
                        CROSS JOIN 
  Bachelier        b4_  
                        LEFT JOIN
  Bac              b0_   ON b0_.bachelier_cne = b4_.cne 
                        AND b0_.etabBac_id = e5_.codeLieu 
                        AND b0_.typeBac_id = t3_.codeType
                        AND b0_.mentionBac_id = m2_.codeMention
```

Try changing the `FROM` clause as above. The only other option I see is the removal of the `CROSS JOIN  Bachelier  b4_`, as no column of this table is included in the `SELECT`.

---

After more comments and a request, here is one final trial:

```
SELECT COUNT( b0_.id ) AS sclr0, 
       d1_.codeLieu AS codeLieu1, d1_.nomLieu AS nomLieu2, 
         d1_.lngLieu AS lngLieu3, d1_.latLieu AS latLieu4, 
       m2_.libelleMention AS libelleMention5, 
       t3_.libelleType AS libelleType6
FROM 
  TypeBac          t3_  
    CROSS JOIN 
  MentionBac       m2_  
    CROSS JOIN 
  Delegation       d1_  
    INNER JOIN 
  EtablissementBac e5_   ON e5_.delegation_id = d1_.codeLieu 
    LEFT JOIN
  Bac              b0_   ON b0_.etabBac_id = e5_.codeLieu 
                        AND b0_.typeBac_id = t3_.codeType
                        AND b0_.mentionBac_id = m2_.codeMention 
WHERE m2_.codeMention IN ('TB',  'B')
  AND t3_.codeType IN ('114',  '129')
  AND EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
          FROM Bac b
          WHERE b.etabBac_id = e5_.codeLieu 
            AND b.typeBac_id = t3_.codeType
            AND b.mentionBac_id = m2_.codeMention 
        )
GROUP BY 
    d1_.codeLieu, 
    m2_.codeMention, m2_.libelleMention, 
    t3_.codeType, t3_.libelleType, t3_.abbrType ;
```

Comment: Thank you @ypercube for all those explanations, it almost solves my problem. There's just one more little problem. For the nomLieu2 where all sclr0 are equal to zero, I don't want them to appear. Can you help me with that ?

Comment: I'm confused now, the description in the question says that all this trouble is exactly for showing up those rows.

Comment: Your code solves my problem in a way, but there's something extra : all the nomLieu2 of the table appear. What I want to appear is only those where at least one sclr0 is not null. All the nomLieu2 where all sclr0 are null can be avoided. Do you get my point ?

Comment: I mean now it's already great with the code you suggested. But I want to exclude the nomLieu2 where all sclr0 are null. But if for one nomLieu2, there's one (at least) sclr0 which is not null, I want all the other sclr0 to be put to zero.

Comment: would you please help me with the last thing ?

Comment: Oh, I've just seen it. Um.. what does `d` in `d.codeLieu` stand for in the subrequest ?

Comment: I changed the subrequest to this :
    `SELECT e.delegation_id 
          FROM EtablissementBac e 
          INNER JOIN Delegation d
          ON e.delegation_id = d.codeLieu
          INNER JOIN Bac b
          ON b.etabBac_id = e.codeLieu 
          GROUP BY e.delegation_id`

But I still have the same result (= all the nomLieu2)

Comment: Sorry, it had error, corrected  now. For the issue you have, without sample data (and sample of wanted output), I don't think anyone would be able to help you. You can load table definitions and data in **[sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/)** and a link in your question so everyone can test.

Comment: Well, I made a new screenshot (look at the link in my new edit). CHTOUKA AIT BAHA and SIDI IFNI both have all zeros in the first column (which is slcr0), so I want to exclude them from my request. The others should be kept since they contain numbers. Is that clear enough as my wanted output ?

Comment: Are there Nulls in the `Bac.id` column? See my edit. The sql-fiddle says no but it would be really helpful if you had added a few rows of data there.

Comment: There are no nulls in the Bac.id

Comment: There are no nulls in the `Bac.id` column. And I still get the same results. I'd love to add some data, but for this request, I need to add thousands so that you can get the results I get. Moreover, I'm not allowed to provide any data of the database. I'm really sorry and so grateful for your help. But if you got the problem I want to solve, you can explain tp me using an example of yours.